# Integrating over 3D space with inequality bounds. A very weird result.

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

in my studies of risk theory I was calculating a certain probability and a part of it was
$$p=\mathbb{P}(\theta_1+\theta_2\leq3, \theta_1+\theta_2+\theta_3>3),$$
where $\theta_i$ are independent copies of $\theta$ which is a random variable uniformly distributed on $[1;2]$. I got stuck here. I tried expressing p in terms of a probability and conditional probability:
$$p=\mathbb{P}(\theta_1+\theta_2\leq3)\cdot\mathbb{P}(\theta_1+\theta_2+\theta_3>3|\theta_1+\theta_2\leq3).$$
The first part is easy enough to see geometrically or to even calculate as an integral (although now I am beginning to doubt even this):
$$\mathbb{P}(\theta_1+\theta_2\leq3)=\int_1^2\int_{3-x}^2\mathop{dy}\mathop{dx}=\frac{1}{2}.$$
The problem is with the second part, let's call it $q=\mathbb{P}(\theta_1+\theta_2+\theta_3>3|\theta_1+\theta_2\leq3)$. I tried three methods and all three yielded different results! They were:

1. Thinking about it. No matter what, the minimum value a $\theta_i$ can obtain is $1$, so of course the probability that the sum of three copies of $\theta$ is more than $3$ has to be $1$, so $q=1$.
2. Looking at the region in a 3D calculator. I used geogebra for this (https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/zbf99hb3). You can clearly see half of the cubic region is inbetween the two bounds, so of course $q=\frac{1}{2}$.
3. Writing out the integrals. I replaced $\theta_1$ with $x$, $\theta_2$ with $y$ and $\theta_3$ with $z$ for simplicity. We have the conditions:
   \begin{equation}
       \begin{cases}
           x+y+z>3,\\
           x+y\leq 3,\\
           1\leq x,y,z\leq 2
       \end{cases}\,
   \end{equation}
   Rearranging we get:
   \begin{equation}
       \begin{cases}
           z>3-x-y,\\
           y\leq 3-x,\\
           1\leq x,y,z\leq 2
       \end{cases}\,
   \end{equation}
   And so we have our bounds for integration:
   $$q=\int_1^2\int_1^{3-x}\int_{3-x-y}^2\mathop{dz}\mathop{dy}\mathop{dx}$$
   The problem is, this yields the answer $q=\frac{5}{6}$. I checked it with WolframAlpha and calculated it by hand twice.

So, is the probability $q$ equal to $1$, $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{5}{6}$ or something else entirely? What is wrong with my ways of thinking? At least two of them have to be flawed, yet I cannot see what is wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\theta \sim U(1, 2)$, it follows that $\theta_1 + \theta_2 + \theta_3 \geq 3$, and thus $\mathbb{P}(\theta_1 + \theta_2 + \theta_3 > 3) = 1$. Hence, $\mathbb{P}(\theta_1 + \theta_2 \leq 3, \theta_1 + \theta_2 + \theta_3 > 3) = \mathbb{P}(\theta_1 + \theta_2 \leq 3) = \boxed{\frac{1}{2}}$, as you said.

For your third method, you forgot that $z \geq 1$ as well, so you should really have bound $z \geq \max(1, 3 - x - y)$, which should yield the correct answer.

Comment: Ohh, now I see. In my 2nd method I was not looking at $q$, that was the whole answer. Fixing up the third method also yields $\frac{1}{2}$, although I am not sure on how I would calculate that by hand. Thank you!!!